# Upload files using Flask and Graphene?

Tags: python, flask, graphql, graphene-python

Trying to make a mutation that does file uploads. 
This is what I tried without GraphQL and it works fine:

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def uploadFile():
    for key in request.files:
        file = request.files[key]
        file.save(os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, file.filename))

    return 'uploaded'
```

Not sure how to do it in GraphQL though, I want to include this in [my example repo](https://github.com/savovs/flask-graphene-hello) so that everyone knows how to do it. [Here's what](https://github.com/jaydenseric/apollo-upload-server) I use for file uploads in Node.js

Answer (score -1):

Say, you are uploading a photo.

```
class Upload(graphene.Scalar):
    def serialize(self):
        pass

class UploadPhoto(graphene.Mutation):
    class Input:
        photo = Upload()
        id = graphene.String(required=True)

    ok = graphene.Boolean()

    @staticmethod
    def mutate(root, args, context, info):
        files = request.files
        photo = files['variables.photo']

        return UploadPhoto(ok=True)

class MyMutations(graphene.ObjectType):
    upload_photo = UploadPhoto.Field()

schema = graphene.Schema(query=XXX, mutation=MyMutations, types=[Upload])
```

Courtesy: https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/issues/101#issuecomment-331079482